# The length of childNodes XML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, dom

> I have 2 same together,First:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        var x, i, xmlDoc;
        var txt = "";
        var text = "<book>" + 
        "<title>Everyday Italian</title>" +
        "<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>" +
        "<year>2005</year>" +
        "</book>";
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
        x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
        document.write(x.length);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Second File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DOM XML</title>
    <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
                xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
                x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
                document.write(x.length);
            }   
        };
        xhttp.open('get','book3.xml',true);
        xhttp.send();
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

> and book3.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <title>Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
</book>
```

I think text variable in the first code same with code in book3.xml, but when I print x.length, so the result in top is "3" and below in is "7". I try to many times but It's not change. Can you help me for the reason ???

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your xml file has 4 text nodes that are children of the `<book>` element. All the whitespace between the tags make up these text nodes. IN your js string the white space is not there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book><!--  child node 1
 --><title>Everyday Italian</title><!--  child node 3
 --><author>Giada De Laurentiis</author><!--  child node 5
 --><year>2005</year><!--  child node 7 -->
</book>
```